# Stop automatic dismissal of keyboard on iOS/disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal not called

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

I would like to be able to have another control become the first responder yet keep the keyboard showing to the user.

I found disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal in UIViewController and overrode it but it never get's called (iOS 5.0)

Is there a reason this method would not get called?  Is there another way to keep the keyboard showing even though it's not required by the first responder?

Comment: That method never gets called because it only relates to view controllers that were presented modally. Presenting a VC modally has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it felt a bit like a hack what I did was make override canBecomeFirstResponder on UIView to return YES and then implement the UIKeyProtocol

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

But did nothing on key press. This way the keyboard stays open but the keys don't matter.