# Dismiss iOS keyboard only on 'Done' button

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView inside which some text editing goes on. However I can't guarantee that an input will always have focus within the UIWebView, and so the keyboard keeps dismissing itself. Is there an easy way to ensure that the keyboard will stay open until the 'Done' button on the keyboard is pressed, and under no circumstances dismiss before that?

Comment: how dismiss the keyboard now?

Comment: I think there could be a work around. seeing as it is webview, you can run javascript to capture keypress. If you capture the done button, then allow the keyboard event continue. Otherwise you can do a focus in javascript which will fire up the keyboard again. This is only a suggestion to try :D

Comment: @Ilario the keyboard pops up when you focus on the web view, because it contains a text area. But it gets dismissed if focus leaves the text area, even for a moment, which happens because there are some other elements in the web view with which a user can interact.

Comment: @mashdup yeah, I can easily grab focus back again, but it's a bit distracting repeatedly showing and hiding it.

Comment: I suppose what you can do is subclass the uiwebview and intercept any keyboard dismisal. I found this that you can put in your uiwebview subclass http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411562/stop-automatic-dismissal-of-keyboard-on-ios-disablesautomatickeyboarddismissal-n

Comment: @mashdup that doesn't seem to work - the keyboard stays open but the accessory view (<> buttons and 'Done') hides, and the UIKeyboardWillHide notification still gets sent.